# req.user is undefined, using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

i am new to typescript and i am working on an Oauth2.0 project with passport, the req.user returns undefined and i dont know why, here is my code.

```js
function checkLoggedIn(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any {
  console.log('current user is: ', req.user);
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: 'you must log in',
    });
  }
  next();
}
```

i always get undefined when logging the user

```
current user is:  undefined
```

anyone knows what is the course of this?

- the whole code

```js
async function verifyCallback(accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) {
  const newUser = {
    googleId: profile.id,
    displayName: profile.displayName,
    email: profile.emails[0].value,
    Image: profile.photos[0].value,
  };

  try {
    let user = await Oauth.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

    if (user) {
      done(null, profile);
    } else {
      user = await Oauth.create(newUser);
      done(null, profile);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

passport.use(new Strategy(AUTH_OPTIONS, verifyCallback));

// save the session to the cookie
passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
});

// load the session from the cookie
passport.deserializeUser((id: any, done) => {
  done(null, id)
});

app.use(helmet());

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  keys: [ config.COOKIE_KEY_1, config.COOKIE_KEY_2 ],
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

function checkLoggedIn(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any {
  console.log('current user is: ', req.user);
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: 'you must log in',
    });
  }
  next();
}

// Authentication route
router.get(
  '/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'],
  }),
);

router.get(
  '/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
    successRedirect: '/user',
    session: true,
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log('google called us back');
  },
);

router.get('/user', checkLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user: any = await Oauth.findOne({ username: String });
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/')
});

router.get('/failure', (req, res) => {
  res.send('failed to log in');
});
```

Comment: what it shows when you log req? also check whether Request import from express

Comment: This is unrelated to TypeScript, it's a setup issue in your app (passport not configured properly, sessions not working correctly, etc).

Comment: What makes you think `req.user` should be set? Share that code as well.

Comment: @YJR yes, the request is imported from express

Comment: @Evert, when i load the callback url i get, my user detail on my browser, so i want to protect the user route and i need the user data to do that. i just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

**
Try this
**

*You can change the value (req.user) to (req.body.user)*

```
function checkLoggedIn(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any {
  console.log('current user is: ', req.body.user);
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: 'you must log in',
    });
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: tried this and still not working!